# Jquery is resetting after dynamic changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have a chartist.js bar graph. I want to customize x-axis labels. I wrote some following jquery for flipping first and last name and then add '...' at the end if the length of the text is more than 11 characters.

```
$(function () {
        $('#AssignedLineChart .ct-labels, #ResolvedBarChart .ct-labels').find('.ct-label.ct-horizontal').each(function () {
            var label = $(this).text();
            var splitLabel = label.split(",");
            var newLabel = splitLabel[1] + ", "+splitLabel[0];
            if (newLabel.length > 13) {
                newLabel = newLabel.substring(0, 10) + "...";
            }
            $(this).text(newLabel);
        });
    });
```

It applied fine when I load the page first time. There are some select options on bar charts for displaying individual ranges. When I select them the labels go back to their previous state. Selecting options are changing DOM. This also happens when I open inspect element tab.

Is there a way to use find or each method on dynamically changed elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
```

This is only applied when the page finishes loading and get fired 1 time only.

> Selecting options are changing DOM.

So the current process is like:

1. Page finishes loading.
2. The label got changed by document ready event. (*)
3. The label got changed by other events, this case, the select options. (**)

So, it changed the DOM dynamically and nothing like above (*) changes the label again.

So, to change the label after select options, you need to change it in the callback function of what is done after select options in the above mentioned (**).